# XPATH to select all nodes which are not empty

Tags: xml, xpath

How do I select ALL nodes which have some value and are not empty? For example, I have the following XML:

```
    <bbb>
        <aaa/>
        <bbb/>
        <ccc>23</ccc>
        <ddd/>
        <eee>Health</eee>
        <fff/>
    </bbb>
```

Here I want to select those nodes which are children of bbb and have some value i.e. the nodes ccc and eee.

Comment: Do you want to select nodes that contain only whitespace too or should they be ignored?

Comment: whitespace should be ignored @DanielHaley

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> select those nodes which are children of bbb and have some value

If you want to include nodes that only contain whitespace, try:

```
/bbb/*[string()]
```

If you want to ignore nodes that only contain whitespace (`<x>   </x>`), try:

```
/bbb/*[normalize-space()]
```

Comment: I suspect `/bbb/*[not(empty(.))]` would be more efficient on most processors because the value of the node does not need to be accessed and potentially converted.

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
/bbb/*[.!='']
```

All children of bbb where the value is not empty.

Comment: This will also select nodes that only contain whitespace.

Comment: That is true.  I wrote this answer before the OP stated he wanted to ignore nodes with whitespace only.

Comment: Yes my comment was more for the OP (and/or future visitors) so that he/she was aware of what was selected by your xpath. Nothing wrong with your answer at all for the original question. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Get all nodes only if has text value:

```
/bbb/*[text()]
```

Comment: This will also select nodes that only contain whitespace.